# Faster to do a 'WHERE IN (SELECT)' or 'WHERE x = (SELECT)'

Tags: mysql

Which select statement is better?

```
SELECT *
FROM  aTable
WHERE aField in (
    SELECT xField 
    FROM   bTable
    WHERE  yField > 5
);
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM  aTable
WHERE (
    SELECT yField
    FROM   bTable
    WHERE  aTable.aField = bTable.xField
) > 5;
```

Comment: Is the second one even legal syntax? Usually questions that start with a `WHERE xxx IN (...)` compare it to an `OUTER JOIN` and `WHERE yyy IS NULL` or `NOT EXISTS (...)`. If that's your question, [here's your answer](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

Comment: The first one in my oppinion is more solid. I'm pretty sure you'll get errors from the second.

Comment: Answering my own question above: Yes, apparently the second example is valid. Didn't get the courtesy of a reply, but checked it myself with a local MySQL install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They produce very similar execution plans *(on my test tables, which are tiny; YMMV, always profile real data)*, and there's a third alternative you may want to consider instead:

The first:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE aField in (SELECT xField FROM bTable WHERE yField > 5);
```

```
+----+--------------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table  | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | aTable | ALL   | NULL          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | bTable | range | bTable_yField | bTable_yField | 5       | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

The second:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE (SELECT yField FROM bTable WHERE aTable.aField = bTable.xField) > 5;
```

```
+----+--------------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | aTable | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | bTable | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Both result in a dependent subquery; on my example tables, the first one gets the benefit of the index (I assume `bTable.yField` is indexed) while the second doesn't.

You can avoid the dependent subquery and get better up-front filtering using a `JOIN`:

The third alternative:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM aTable INNER JOIN bTable On aTable.aField = bTable.xField WHERE bTable.yField > 5;
```

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bTable | range | bTable_yField | bTable_yField | 5       | NULL |    2 | Using where                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | aTable | ALL   | NULL          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
```

Again, though, you really have to profile with **your** schema and **your** representative real-world data, as the optimizer may make different decisions.

More comparing these sorts of techniques in [this excellent article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) by [quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi).

---

For reference, here is how I created `aTable` and `bTable` (as you didn't provide definitions) and tested your queries:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE aTable (aField INT, aMore VARCHAR(200));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE bTable (xField INT, yField INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO aTable (aField, aMore) VALUES (1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three'), (4, 'Four');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO bTable (xField, yField) VALUES (1, 10), (2, 2), (3, 20), (4, 4);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE INDEX bTable_yField ON bTable(yField);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE aField in (SELECT xField FROM bTable WHERE yField > 5);
+--------+-------+
| aField | aMore |
+--------+-------+
|      1 | One   |
|      3 | Three |
+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE (SELECT yField FROM bTable WHERE aTable.aField = bTable.xField) > 5;
+--------+-------+
| aField | aMore |
+--------+-------+
|      1 | One   |
|      3 | Three |
+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the second one translates to correlated sub-query semantics and so is costly, compared to the first one. The best would be to just JOIN the two tables, as follows:

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM 
    aTable a
    JOIN bTable b
    ON aTable.aField = bTable.xField
WHERE 
    b.xField > 5
```

This will save you from large number of results in the IN clause, in case of the first query, that would make the query execution slower, and at times results in overflow error (SQL Server used to have a limit of 32767 values in the IN clause after which it used to throw this overflow error).

Comment: Both of the OP's examples require dependent subqueries. +1 for pointing out the `JOIN` alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Alot depends on the indexing of the tables and whether indexed columns are used within the join condition.  A combination of these will go some way as to how the SQL Engine 'decides' to construct the query internally and will ultimately affect the query performance.  Not too sure on MySQL but certainly SQL Server will allow an Execution Plan to be created which will show potential bottlenecks.